# CSS diagonal line separating 2 images

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have been given the task of recreating this mockup in html and css. I have been fiddling around for the past few hours trying to use clip paths and borders, but I havent been able to achieve the results of the mockup.

I have been given 2 image resources, and the images do not include the text or the button.

```css
#index-custom-content {
    height: 40rem;
    padding-bottom: -20%;
}

#index-custom-content div:nth-of-type(1){
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

#index-custom-content div:nth-of-type(2) {
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 90%, 100% 100%, 0 10%);
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: relative;
    top: -2em;
}

#index-custom-content div:nth-of-type(3){
    position: relative;
    top: -20%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
        <div id="index-custom-content">
            <div><img src="bare-rolig.jpg"></div>
            <div>asd</div>
            <div><img src="bestseller.gif"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question is how do I achieve the diagonal line separating the 2 images, when given 2 images of unequal size (both width and height). Which also can be resized and the proportions will be correct and the width of the line also remains constant.

Any advice or a point in the right direction is greatly apprectiated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clip-path with negative margin:

```css
.first,
.second{
  --s:100px;
  height:300px;
}

.first {
  background:red;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 calc(100% - var(--s)));
}

.second {
  background:green;
  /* a little smaller than --s to create a gap */
  margin-top: calc(var(--s) * -1  + 10px);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% var(--s),100% 100%,0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly! However could you explain to me what's going on with  the --s?

Comment: @JosephCarpenter it's a CSS variable to avoid repeating the same value twice, not really needed. You can manually write the value

Comment: Since the margin-top is dependant somewhat on the variable `--s` I'd suggest `margin-top: calc(var(--s) * -1  + 10px);`

Comment: @FabrizioCalderanlovestrees feel free to edit, it's a wiki answer ;)