# skew between 2 images

Tags: css

I want to have a transversal gap between two images, and I don't know how to make my images stayed normal after.
I used the function skew and I am not able to make it work correctly.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.skew-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 20px;
  /* Adjust the gap width */
}

.skew-wrapper img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.skew-wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  /* Adjust the gap width */
  width: 200%;
  /* Adjust the width of the gap */
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Adjust the color of the gap */
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  /* Adjust the skew angle */
  z-index: -1;
  /* Ensure the gap is behind the images */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="skew-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/815/200/200.jpg" alt="Your Image 1">
  </div>
  <div class="skew-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/200/200.jpg" alt="Your Image 2">
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know this isn't making any transformations.

Comment: I would like to separate my two images by a transversal gap from bottom left to top right without transforming my images.

Comment: we are missing some real image and result expexted to understand fully what you are trying to achieve. There is no background image, but image tags ...

Comment: I don't understand what the pseudo-elements are supposed to do. They are placed beneath the image (z-index: 0), but the `.skew-wrapper` container has `overflow: hidden`, so the (already transparent) pseudo-elements are, therefore, fully hidden by the image.

Comment: your skew() function is working but you don't see it as color is transparant and z-index is -1. if you change color to white and z-index to 10 you will see it. you also have 2 diagonals over your images (as you have 2 skew-wrapper). Maybe you need to do that on your container or maybe follow this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581797/css-diagonal-line-separating-2-images) and using clip-path()